# Does this sequence of operators in Hilbert space, given by an algorithm, terminate

Tags: functional-analysis, algorithms, recursive-algorithms

Let $H$ be an infinitedimensional Hilbert space and $T$ a compact
selfadjoint operator in it. Consider the following

---

**Algorithm:**

Let
$$
H_{1}=H,\ T_{1}=T
$$
and let $\lambda_{1}$ be that eigenvalue of $T_{1}$ whose absolute
value equals $\left\Vert T_{1}\right\Vert $ (there is a theorem that
tells me that compact selfadjoint operators $T$ always possess an eigenvalue
$\lambda$, such that $\left|\lambda\right|=\left\Vert T\right\Vert $)
and $f_{1}$ the associated normed eigenvector.

Now let 
$$
H_{2}=\left\{ f_{1}\right\} ^{\perp},\ T_{2}=T\Bigr|_{H_{2}}
$$
(one can check that setting $T_{2}=T\Bigr|_{H_{2}}$ is welldefined)
and $\lambda_{2}$ be again the eigenvalue of $T_{2}$ such that $\left\Vert T_{2}\right\Vert $
and $f_{2}$ be again its corresponding normed eigenvector.

Continuing let 
$$
H_{3}=\left\{ f_{1},f_{2}\right\} ^{\perp},\ T_{3}=T\Bigr|_{H_{3}}
$$
and so on...

This algorithm shall terminate of $T_{n}$ is the zero operator for
some $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

---

Now my question is: If $T$ isn't a finite rank operator, is it possible
that this algorithm stops after a *finite* number of steps?  If yes, can one please provide me with detailed
example of such an operator $T$ (or otherwise a proof that this algorithm
never terminates )?

Comment: Right; I corrected my typo now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the algorithm stops after $n$ iterations, then you have $T_n$ is the zero operator on $H_n$.

Since $H = \mathbb{sp}\{f_k\}_{k=1}^{n-1} \bigoplus H_n$, if $x \in H$, then $x = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \alpha_k f_k + y$, where $y \in H_n$. Then you have 
$$Tx = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \alpha_k T f_k +T y = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \alpha_k T f_k +T_n y = \sum_{k=1}^{n-1} \alpha_k T f_k \in \mathbb{sp}\{f_k\}_{k=1}^{n-1}.$$
Hence $T$ is a finite rank operator.